# Change the converter on a binding in Vaadin 10 Flow?

Tags: data-binding, vaadin, converters, vaadin10, vaadin-flow

When establishing a binding with binding-builder, we can specify a converter to mediate between types such as using a `String` oriented `TextField` to work with a backing value of type `Integer`.

```
binder
.forField( this.phaseField )
.withConverter( 
    new StringToIntegerConverter( "Must enter an integer number" ) 
)
.bind( Panel::getPhase , Panel::setPhase ) ;
```

Is there some way to get/change/replace that converter later, after the binding is established?

Comment: You just need to remove the Binding and then add it again with the new Converter. You can't just hot swap the Converter

Comment: You could also implement a wrapper/proxy converter that delegates to a another converter which can be exchanged then.

Answer (score 0):

Per comments posted on the Question…

## No

No, you cannot replace the `Converter` by itself.

## Workarounds

A couple of possible workarounds:

- **Remove the binding**, replacing it with a fresh `Binder.Binding` using your different `Converter`.
- Implement the original `Converter` as a **wrapper/proxy** that delegates to another converter. Switch out that delegate as need be.